# Extracting data from drupal view not getting all the data

Tags: php, android, api, drupal

I have a view in Drupal that is displaying the name ,logo, phone number and phone type . I have created a php script to extract this from the view so that I can run this in the android app and pull the data into it (as JSON) I have successfully created the JSON output with the node_id and the company name(title) but when I attempt to grab the phone information I get null values I have attached the code below.

```
foreach($view->result AS $company) {
    $companylist = array();
    $data = $company->_field_data['nid']['entity'];
    $companylist['company'] = $company->node_title;
    $companylist['nid'] = $company->nid;
    $data2 = field_get_items('node',$data,'field_data_field_companyphone_node_entity_type');
    $phone  = entity_load('field_collection_item',array($data2[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']));
    $companylist['type'] = $phone[0];
    $companylist['phone'] =$phone[1];   
    $return[]=$companylist;
}
   }
return $return;
  }
```

Comment: 3 `}` for 1 `{`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution by using a wrapper in my code I also create an inner for each loop for the field collection hopefully this will help others in the future the updated code has been included below

```
$fc_fields = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_companyphone');
    if (!empty($fc_fields)){
        $field = field_view_value('node',$node, 'field_companyphone', $fc_fields[0]);
        foreach ($field['entity']['field_collection_item'] as $id => $field_collection){
            // load the field collection item entity
            $field_collection_item = field_collection_item_load($id);
            // wrap the entity and make it easier to get the values of fields
            $field_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $field_collection_item);       


            // all values from a field collection
            $field_collection_phone_type_item   = $field_wrapper->field_companyphone_type->value(); // an array of phone type data  


            $companylist['type'] = $field_collection_phone_type_item->name;
            $companylist['phone']   = $field_wrapper->field_phone_phone->value();

        }
    }


    $return[]=$companylist;
```